# Help to understand the metaphor: *this letter* --> *something felt like a freight train*

Tags: metaphors

> CEO Kevin Meuret told the St. Louis Post-Dispatch that the hacking was probably committed by an ex-employee. “I’m a father of three daughters, and that young lady getting that [response] is horrible,” Meuret told the paper. “That young lady opened **something that must have felt like a freight train**, and that’s unacceptable.”

According to the previous context, the [response] is:

> “Thank you for your interest in careers at Mantality Health. Unfortunately, we do not consider candidates that have suggestive ‘ghetto’ names. We wish you the best in your career search.”

I don't get the analogy: *this letter* --> *something felt like a freight train*. Maybe, it leverages the **big and heavy** nature of a freight train? I'm really not sure about it.

The [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/woman-says-job-application-denied-name-ghetto-004856379.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! It's meant to convey that the big, heavy train harms her. I see it as missing some words along the lines of

> That young lady opened something that must have felt like a freight train **[running her over]**, and that’s unacceptable.

It must have really hurt, like a freight train running you over, to discover that you were rejected because they thought your name was "ghetto".

Comment: When news hits "like a (figurative) freight train," the result is emotional devastation. A similar, oft-used phrase is "like a ton of bricks."

Comment: Sounds like "a freight train" is a common device to express this kind of emotional devastation?

Comment: Thanks, @J.R. Is it really that common? It didn't register with me that way. Maybe you should write an answer.

Comment: [Both phrases are in use](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=like+a+freight+train%2Clike+a+ton+of+bricks&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), and they can be used figuratively in many ways: _the storm hit the coast like a ton of bricks; the market dropped like a freight train; the defenseman skated into the puck carrier like a ton of bricks; the firetruck screamed down the street like freight train_.

Comment: @dan: Comparing the impact of something to that of a **train** striking or a train crash is a (hackneyed, overused)  form of exaggeration.  *The news hit me like a freight train.*